# jQuery replaceWith not working for image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, replacewith

I am trying to select an image, and then replace that image with a div and an alternate image and div within that div, but to no avail.

```
$("img[src='/brand/logo.png']").replaceWith("
    <div class=\"brander\">
        <img src=\"https:\/\/cache.graphicslib.brand.com/new-logo.png\">
        <div class=\"value-propositions\">Low price guarantee!</div>
    </div>
");
```

Nothing appears to be happening, however, and I have tested to see if the selector is finding the image (with the code below), which it is. I am not sure if the selector is not selecting the entire image tag, or if I am making an error elsewhere.

```
if ($("img[src='/brand/logo.png']").length) {
    alert ("The selector works!");
}
```

Any input is welcome. I'm fairly new to JS so, I happily welcome all criticism and advice.

Comment: First and second selectors are different in the value of src attribute. Is it intentional?

Comment: Your first snippet isn't valid javascript - multiline strings are not supported in this language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your selector may not be working.

`var derp = $('img[src$="brand/logo.png"]').replaceWith(" \
    <div class=\"brander\"> \
        <img src=\"https:\/\/cache.graphicslib.brand.com/new-logo.png\"> \
        <div class=\"value-propositions\">Low price guarantee!</div> \
    </div>");`

`img[src$=` is src 'ends with' may be helpful.  (note the \ and new line, that is how you can line break like that in javascript)

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutmatt/TcE5c/12/

Comment: Is derp a technical term ;)

Comment: Thank you so much. Got it working. I do have one question--does replaceWith also replace an element's children? i.e. If I select <div id="parent>, and attach replaceWith, will #parent and it's children be replaced, or just #parent?

Comment: based on the jquery document: http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/ and my new jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TcE5c/16/  The only dom element 'replaced' is the one selected, not the children  HOWEVER you may want to double check this in your dom as it seems to pull the children and add them to the parent of the removed item in my example.  Don't forget to mark my answer as selected if it is 'correct'